# Unhandled exception: Connection timed out | Flutter | REST API

Tags: python, flutter, api, rest, flask

I have built a REST API using Flask framework in Python and it works completely fine when tested via Postman. But when I make requests using an android emulator, I get an exception displaying "Connection timed out".

I am aware that the localhost for android emulator is ***10.0.2.2:8000*** and ***not 127.0.0.1:5000***, and I am making the request accordingly. But I have still no luck in receiving the response that I want.

**API code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return {"message": "Hello and Welcome"}


@app.route("/getkeywords", methods=["POST"])
def getKeywords():
    res = request.get_json()
    
    text = res["text"]
    data = extractKeywords(text)
    # print(text)

    return jsonify({"data": data})


from rake_nltk import Rake

def extractKeywords(text: str):
    r = Rake()
    r.extract_keywords_from_text(text)
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for rating, keyword in r.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores():
        data[rating].append(keyword)

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Flutter code:**

```
Future<void> getKeywords(String text) async {
  String mainURL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/getkeywords";

  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(mainURL), body: {"text": text});
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception("Failed to get data");
  }
}
```

**Debug console output:**
[image]

Comment: I see you haven't explicitly json encoded the body. Can you paste the `response.statusCode` and `response.body` values in order to further scope the issue

Comment: @sigmapie8 I don't get any of the print statements as soon as this function executes. It feels almost as if the execution has been halted for a good 2 to 3 minutes and then I get the debug console output.

Comment: may be try it with real device first just to ensure that the isse is with emulator. If the real device also fails, the problem might be with the backend.

Comment: Uh okay, so to do this, I would have to host the backend at some domain which would incur some monetary cost. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You won't have to. If the backend is currently in your local machine, you just connect to same wifi and you'd be able to access the same with your phone

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I'll try with my phone and let you know.

Comment: @sigmapie8 I hosted my backend at a domain and the android emulator seems to be able to send API requests now. I don't receive a "Connection timed out" exception. The 'get' requests are executed successfully with a status code of 200. However, I am getting an error code of 400 when I try the 'post' request. When I make the same request via Postman, everything seems to fine there (status code 200 and I get my expected response). Any idea what has gone wrong here?

Comment: most likely the fault is at the Flutter side. Try json encoding your body as I see you're expecting a json in the backend code

Comment: Json encoding will convert the map to a string which is not what the API is expecting; it is expecting a map with key-value pairs. I think json encoding wouldn't help it but I will do it so we can eliminate every single possibility of error.

Comment: @sigmapie8 I tried json encoding the body but still got no progress; error code 400. I even made a new dart project and made calls to my API from there, to rule out if the emulator was at fault. Still got the error code 400.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IP address of your machine running python backend.

Checkout your IP address with `ipconfig` on Windows or `ifconfig` on Linux\MacOS.

Comment: I tried using my machine's IPv4 address and the same exception (Connection timed out) got thrown. No luck.

Comment: Did you use server port? I don't know which one you use for server. 8080? 5000?

Comment: I used the same port 8000.